# Site intro text is out of date

Tags: support, status-completed

I noticed that when I go to the main AVP site, the little box on the left hand side said that this site was for music composers. Aren't questions about music somewhat off topic, as they should be on the musicians site instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch.  When we adjusted the scope of the site to include video, we updated the [FAQ](https://video.stackexchange.com/faq) but missed the other spots.

I've edited this text to match what the FAQ says:

> engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of audio, video, and media creation

Comment: Thank you very much!